# Runtime of recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, erlang, runtime, time-complexity

I am trying to find the runtime of this function:

```
myst_fun_1([]) -> 0;
myst_fun_1(ListUsed = [_ | Tail]) -> length(ListUsed) + myst_fun_1(Tail).
```

Since this the length function is `O(N)` and `myst_fun_1` is called `N` times, would the runtime be `O(N^2)`? I would like to know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes! as N*N is N^2 but what you can do is you can simply store the `length(ListUsed)` in a variable and it will no longer calculate the length at each iteration/recursion , that will make it a `O(N)`

Comment: provided I believe (from what I understand in the code) `myst_fun_1` executes `N` times

Comment: The value of `length(ListUsed)` changes every time when `myst_fun_1(ListUsed)` is executed so the length won't be able to be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
myst_fun_1([]) -> 0;

myst_fun_1(ListUsed) -> 
    myst_fun_1(length(ListUsed), ListUsed).

myst_fun_1(Length, [_ | Tail]) ->
    Length + myst_fun_1(Length-1, Tail).
```

O(N)

Answer (score -2):

`length/1` is a BIF and will run much faster than `myst_fun_1/1`, so it's much more likely to be O(N) than O(N^2).

Comment: Should it not take into account the recursive call? I am looking for the worst-case time complexity.

Comment: length/& is a BIF but nevertheless has to count all the element 1 by 1 and thus is O(N).

Comment: Have you profiled the execution time of `length/1`? Using eprof or fprof will give you the realistic execution time results.